# Accessing an explicit conversion operator from F#

Tags: f#, npgsql

I am getting the following error when reading date values out of postgresql using npgsql:

```
This expression was expected to have type
    DateTime    
but here has type
    NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDate
```

Now the npgsql docs refer to an explicit operator being defined:

```
[C#]
public static explicit operator DateTime(
    NpgsqlDate date
);
```

but I can't figure out how to access this from F#.

There are several kludgy, longhand ways of achieving what I need, but I am disappointed and frustrated that I was unable to find a way of accessing the inbuilt cast.

I tried the old Convert.ToDateTime(...), but even that doesn't work.

Anybody got a clue?  Thx.

Comment: Have you tried something like `let dateTime : DateTime = NpgsqlDate.op_explicit npgsqlDate`?

Comment: I just tried it, but it says it's not defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explicit conversion operator can be accessed by calling the `op_Explicit` (I had the casing wrong in the earlier comment; I had not tried it myself then) function on the type:

```
let date = NpgsqlDate.op_Explicit npgsqlDate
```

I have also found various places (like in Yan Cui's blog [here](http://theburningmonk.com/2012/08/f-defining-explicit-operator-in-f/)) that define an F# operator like `!>` for (all!) explicit conversions for convenience, so you can just say

```
let date = !> npgsqlDate
```

I think that is a pretty neat way.

Comment: Excellent!  Many thanks.  I knew there had to be a way - with F# there (almost) always is.

Comment: Also thanks for the link to the burning monk blog.  Obviously, I need to brush up my Google-fu coz I failed to find it myself.

Comment: It's not clear how this works if there is more than one explicit conversion defined for a type.  For example, the StackExchange.Redis type RedisValue defines explicit operators for conversion from RedisValue to bool, int, long, uint, ulong, double, float, decimal, etc. How do you know the type of the target of the conversion if I just say "RedisValue.op_Explicit value ?